# Visual studio code is not working properly when I use Dart and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I press enter key on Visual Studio code for flutter and dart It is not moving to next line. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I did find an open issue, is this what you are experiencing? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49796

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard`.
2. Switch the "Use new shortcut in:" dropdown to "Text Editor".
3. Pick the `Edit.BreakLine` command.
4. In the `Press shortcut keys` edit pane press `Shift`+`Enter`